# How to do if the most training data is sparse

Tags: sparse

Consider a problem like this
You have a customer profiling application(say classic telecoms data)
You have customer transactions(lots of them)
you want to find rules
There is a data element which is sparsely populated
ex 
Pets
you are interested in it because you want to explore a hypothesis 
'Are cat owners wealthier than dog owners?'

So you have a lot of data.But the data element you are interested in (pets) is sparse

and you have to create training data for this situation ..

How would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use some "sparse" statistical tools like sparse principal component analysis, sparse linear discriminant analysis etc.